# django search on site taggit

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-taggit, django-tagging

model

```
class Bb(models.Model):    
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_timestamp_path, verbose_name='Pic')
    author = models.ForeignKey(AdvUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Author')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True, verbose_name='Date')
    tags = TaggableManager()       

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for ai in self.additionalimage_set.all():
            ai.delete()
        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Posts'
        verbose_name = 'Post'
        ordering = ['-created_at']
```

view

```
def index(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')                 
    if query: 
        query = request.GET.get('q') #.split(" ")         
        posts = Bb.objects.filter(       
            #tags__name__in=query        

            # this is an invalid request logic:                                   
            tags__name__iexact=request.GET.get('q')    

        ).distinct() 
    else: 
        posts = Bb.objects.all()                     
    paginator = Paginator(posts, 1)    
    page_number = request.GET.get('page') 
    posts = paginator.get_page(page_number) 

    return render(request, 'main/home.html', {'query': query, 'posts': posts})
```

it is necessary to display all the posts in which there are certain some tags. I'm trying to implement a tag-based site search, like on pornhub or rule34. I expect to get the result analog:
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLIec.jpg)

django-taggit is a reusable Django application designed to make adding tagging to your project.

Comment: Please disregard MariaDb example. Instead, what I meant is something analogous to SQL query below: select p.*  from Post p where exists ( select * from PostTags pt
 join Tag t on pt.tag_id = t.tag_id
      where pt.post_id = p.post_id
      and t.name in ('Petya', 'Vasya')  
);